# Factory reset: will home screen order, file, and folder layout, and account usernames and passwords be restored after adding Google account back?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung, factory-reset, google-account, restore

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII device. I would like to know:

- if I configure a Samsung account and factory-reset my device, then when I add the Samsung account back will I get my Android home screens, default home screen, and all the folders and free as well as paid apps they contain be restored so that everything looks exactly the same as it was prior to resetting my device, or do I need to add support for a separate cloud service in order for such configuration to be preserved?
- Also, once I add my Samsung account back after the factory reset, can I also restore all other accounts (Facebook, Twitter, etc..., including these services' username and password) by restoring a single Samsung account?

As you can see, I have both `Samsung account` and `Google` configured under `Settings | General | Accounts`, but I'm not sure which does what:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it can't.

In this case its safer to use a backup app **like [Titanium Backup](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/titanium-backup.html)** which can backup folder structure or full system and downloaded apps data + apk. it'll also keeps your Settings, Home & Lock screen wallpapers, app widgets, bluetooth pairings, bookmarks, call logs, WiFi Access points and every other data which will be backed up with Google or Samsung account.
Also your backups can be restored on any other phone since you can specifically choose which option to restore.

Comment: Will it also back up account passwords to other services such as Facebook and DropBox and restore them? Thanks.

Comment: Great. I've downloaded the Titanium Backup app and I'll see what it can do for me. BTW, do you know what the Samsung app does at all? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnHigginstyne Yes, it will. Think it as a complete-data-transfer app which you won't see any differences between your old and new phone(if you restore all backups). And for your second question Samsung Apps is sth like Google Play but designed exclusively for apps which is developed by Samsung or installed as system apps on Samsung official ROMs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with samsung account but I am sure it works with Google account, if you have backup and restore enabled from day 1 of the account setup. Then you will get everything back.

Comment: Yes, but my question specifically also asks about whether the file and folder structure on the home screens (the ones which can be swiped from left to right) is preserved. If they are, then what happens when the backed up apps and app folders are restored from the google cloud? What if the screen (matrix) is larger / smaller? How would the files and folders be rearranged in this case?

Comment: And when you say "*everything*", do you really mean also the account passwords of other accounts registered on the device?